# gcc 4.8.1 will not make

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu-12.04, gnu-make

I have a new installation of Ubuntu linux and I am trying to update my gcc complier. The latest gcc compiler depends on gmp, mpfr, and mpc, so I downloaded those and placed the source into the gcc 4.8.1 source folder, as instructed.

configure seems to have run just fine. I did not include any options, because none seemed appropriate. I just ran with the defaults.

When I run make, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: C++ compiler missing or inoperational

make[2]: \*** [configure-stage1-libcpp] Error 1    
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/clay/programming/C++/gcc-4.8.1'    
make[1]: \*** [stage1-bubble] Error 2    
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/clay/programming/C++/gcc-4.8.1'    
make: \*** [all] Error 2
```

I am running out of a terminal window as root, and I did a make distclean  and tried a second time, but no dice. I know it can find both gcc and cc because it says so in the make output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aside, don't be root.

Comment: Can you run 'gcc' or 'g++' on the command line?  What does it say?  Just in case, a nice way to install the basics is 'apt-get install build-essential'.

Comment: You are right,m I shouldn't be root, but I haven't used linux for a few years and ran into some permissions issues I'd rather deal with later. Yes, gcc --help runs as expected. I am not familiar with apt-get install build essential. I'll have to look it up.

Comment: Not gcc.  g++.  It's looking for a C++ compiler (see error message).  `gcc` is a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 8):

You need a C++ compiler to build GCC.  On Ubuntu, the C++ compiler is in the package `g++`, separate from `gcc` (which is a C compiler, not a C++ compiler), so be sure to:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 4):

first you should ensure a C++ compiler to build on your machine

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Comment: this solved my problem on CentOS 6 for compiling gcc4.9.1.
Thanks.